# Custom Url is not working for force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites, custom-url, custom-domain

User has a custom url for sites but it is not working.

**For Example:**

Create one Custom Domain 'mydomain.org' in salesforce sandbox.

Create a new force.com site 'myIdeas' and assigned default home page as'Registration'. Create new Custom URL for this site with the above domain (mydomain.org) and path '/reg'.

When previewing or testing the myIdeas site Custom URL, user doesn't see the custom url as 'http://mydomain.org/reg/Registration' instead it shows up as http://mydomain.org/reg/sites/servlet.SiteDebugMode?sitedebugmode=z&rand=85651. Why is the custom url not showing up correctly? See below screenshot:

[image]

How to make the url 'http://mydomain.org/reg/Registration' is accessible.

Can any one have any thoughts on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Salesforce custom domain setup is little bit tricky. So please post your steps as answers so that it will help others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can not test Custom Domain in Sandbox environment. You have to do it in production org only. Also note that **custom root domains** (e.g. http://mydomain.org) can not be added in Salesforce. You can only add sub-domains like http://www.mydomain.org. The main steps are as follows.

1. First create a CNAME record for `www.mydomain.org` as
   `www.mydomain.org.orgid18.live.siteforce.com` in your DNS server.
2. After the CNAME is created in DNS server, add the domain in your org
   **Setup > Domain Management > Domains > "Add a domain"**.
3. After adding the domain go to **Setup > Develop > Sites**. Open your
   site in edit mode by clicking on Site Label. Add "**New
   Custom URL**" by selecting http://www.mydomain.org from the
   list.

The details steps are given in this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653&language=en_US). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may begin with where you "assigned default home page as 'Registration'". See the following Help page on [Adding a Custom URL](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_url_add.htm&language=en_US) where it says the following.

> Once you’ve added domains to the Domain Management page, you can select your domain and site relationships by creating a custom URL. A custom URL consists of the domain and a custom path. The same path name can be used on more than one domain, but it can't be used more than once within the same domain. When adding a custom URL, the / is required and indicates the root. You can add an additional path after the /, but you must at least use the / to indicate the root.

and

> If you want to set a preferred custom URL for authenticated pages and emails that links back to the site or community, then select Site Primary Custom URL. This is only available on the root path for Force.com and Communities sites and not available at all on Site.com sites.

As you mention "Registration", that suggests to me you may be creating a secure site, in which case the URL should begin with `https` not `http` which could be contributing to the problem that you're having.

As you have a servlet that appears on that page, at some point you may need to know about the [URLRewriter Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter_reference.htm#apex_site_urlRewriter_reference) that helps you display user-friendly URLs and links to site visitors.

A reference you may find helpful to you is the [Force.com Sites Implementation Guide](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.pdf).