# Redirect to a custom URL

Tags: community

Hello We have a requirement to create a custom domain for our created commununity in the production org.

So far we have used godaddy to redirect to the custom URL .

So whenever I am typing "shipperman.us" it is redirecting to our community login page

> https://shipperman-portal.force.com/login

Our requirement is that the redirected  URL should be like

> www.shipperman.us

How should we achieve this?

Comment: I have posted answers to similar questions. Please follow these links and let me know if you find any issues https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80385/how-can-i-set-a-custom-domain-in-a-salesforce-community https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88248/custom-url-is-not-working-for-force-com-sites/88285

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `CNAME` record instead so that the DNS views `www.shipperman.us` as an alias for your force.com site instead of redirecting requests there.

In godaddy, you would want to go to your shipperman.us domain, and set up a CNAME record for the www subdomain, set to your force.com site.

Comment: Our Domain name is "www.shipperman.us" . will it be possible to create a CNAME with the same website name

Comment: We have set the CNAME  sor the www subdomain and it is rediredcted to the required page only.But our requirement is that the URL should not change .It should be of the form "www.shipperman.us"

Comment: @SaswataDas that's what the CNAME record should be doing for you. If you post some screenshots of your setup, we might have a better idea of where things are going wrong.